# Number to words program

Tags: c#, numbers, words

I need to write this kind of program:

Write a subroutine to take a numeric value from 1 to 9 as an argument and return the English name (such as one, two, or nine). If the value is out of range, return the original number as the name instead. Test it with some input data; you will have to write some sort of Main program to call the subroutine, for example, using a for loop.

The program should look like this:

```
n = -1 => "-1" 

n = 0 => "0"

n = 1 => "one"
```

I kept trying but for some reason my code is not working.

Below is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
         for (int i = -1; i <= 11; i++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("n = {0} => \"{1}\"", i, NumberToWord(i));
            Console.ReadLine();
           }
    }

    static public string NumberToWord(int number)
    {
        string[] words =
        { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"

            ;
        if ((number >= 1) && (number <= 9))
        {
            return words[number - 1];
        }

        else
        {
            return number.ToString();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger)?

Comment: When you say your code is not working, what's wrong with it? Where are you getting errors? What are the errors?

Comment: The [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) is an awesome tool to work out the "some reason" element.

Comment: As I can see, your program works, it's only missing a closing `}` after `"nine"`. I'll flag to close this as a typo

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] words =
      { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
```

change the array declaration as above.

Comment: 1) It's not necessary to remove either `static` or `public`, it will work with both. 2) `Console.ReadLine();` may be OP's choice to execute one at a time.

Comment: OP forgot a brace. I think that's what he meant.